# Deleting rows from a csv file in GCS bucket

Tags: google-cloud-storage, airflow

A csv file is stored in a gcs bucket. It is required to remove 4500 rows from the csv file each iteration in dag. File size can be big, hence loading the whole file and then uploading its edited version to the gcs bucket is not preferred.

I want to find a way how I can delete rows from the file selectively directly in the gcs bucket through python.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Google Cloud Function to selectively delete rows from a CSV file stored in a GCS bucket.

The workflow will be :
Create a Google Cloud Function >

```
Runtime: Python
Trigger: HTTP
Authentication: Allow unauthenticated invocations
Function to execute: delete_csv_rows
```

In the requirements.txt of function use: google-cloud-storage

Run command to install the required packages

> pip install -r requirements.txt -t .

main.py will have following code sample:

```
import io
import csv
from google.cloud import storage


def delete_csv_rows(request):
    # Get the bucket and file name from the request
    request_json = request.get_json()
    bucket_name = request_json['bucket_name']
    file_name = request_json['file_name']
    
    # Get reference to the CSV file
    client = storage.Client()
    bucket = client.bucket(bucket_name)
    blob = bucket.blob(file_name)
    
    # Read the file into memory and remove rows
    content = blob.download_as_string()
    reader = csv.reader(io.StringIO(content.decode('utf-8')))
    rows_to_keep = []
    for i, row in enumerate(reader):
        if i not in range(4500):
            rows_to_keep.append(row)
    
    # Write the updated file back to GCS
    blob.upload_from_string('\n'.join([','.join(row) for row in rows_to_keep]))
    
    return f'Deleted 4500 rows from {file_name} in {bucket_name}.'
```

For deployment of function, you can use following in Cloud Shell:

```
gcloud functions deploy delete_csv_rows --runtime python38 --trigger-http --allow-unauthenticated --entry-point=delete_csv_rows
```

To test the function, send an HTTP POST request from cloud shell to the function's URL with the following JSON payload:

```
{
    "bucket_name": "your-bucket-name",
    "file_name": "your-file-name.csv"
}
```

This will be able to delete the first 4500 rows from the CSV file in the specified bucket and return a message confirming the deletion.

Comment: Your solution downloads the object from Cloud Storage into memory. The OP states `File size can be big`, which probably means the object is larger than available memory for Cloud Functions.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot modify Cloud Storage objects in Cloud Storage. Objects are `immutable`.

Modifying a CSV requires understanding the file's structure. Cloud Storage does not provide compute features, which would be required to modify a file in place.

You must download the object, apply changes and then upload the modified object.